# Discord.js send message in specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord

I've tried this code

```
if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "sec")){
        if(message.author.id !== '12345678912345') return ;
        message.author.send("Message sent.")
        let msgchanl = client.channels.get('1234567890')
        msgchanl.send("hello")
```

code gives me an error with

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the portion of your code where `client` is set? The error indicates the `client` variable isn't defined.

Comment: var client = new discord.Client();

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it's an outdated function, fixed it by.

```
client.channels.cache.get('1234567890')
```